# If two topologies have the same continuous maps into and out of them, must they be the same?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and let $T_1,T_2$ be topologies on $X$. Assume that for any topological space $Y$, the following conditions hold:
(1) $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous wrt $T_1$ iff $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous wrt $T_2$
(2) $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous wrt $T_2$ iff $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous wrt $T_1$

Must $T_1,T_2$ be the same topologies?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this question?

Comment: HINT: consider the identity map $X \to Y$ where $Y$ is $X$.

Comment: @Crostul What is that hint for?

Comment: @azif00, I suspect the answer is yes, because if two topologies have all the same maps in and out, then they must be very similar, if not the same. Moreover, I can't come up with a counter example.

Comment: FWIW it's bad practice to use notation like "$T_1$" and "$T_2$" to refer to topologies, since [they're already in use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom). (Also, this question would benefit from more context: what have you tried? where did you get stuck? At present it's just a problem statement.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *one, special* topological space $Y$ so that for any set $X$ and for any two topologies $T_1, T_2$ on $X$, we have $T_1=T_2$ if and only if the continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ are the same for $T_1$ and $T_2$.  Can you find such a topological space $Y$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on a set $X$. Let $X_1=Y_1=(X,\tau_1)$ and $X_2=Y_2=(X,\tau_2)$, and let $f$ be the identity function on $X$. Then $f:X_1\to Y_1$ and $f:X_2\to Y_2$ are continuous. If $f:X_2\to Y_1$ and $f:X_1\to Y_2$ are also continuous, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

We only need (2) to see this: suppose $O \in \mathcal{T}_1$. Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, Y\}$, so called Sierpiński space. Define $f_O: X \to Y$ by

$$f_O(x) = \begin{cases}
       0 & x \in O\\
       1 & x \notin O\\
\end{cases}$$

and note that $f_O:(X,\mathcal{T}_1) \to Y$ is continuous as $f_O^{-1}[\{0\}]=O$ is open and $\{0\}$ is the only non-trivial open subset of $Y$.

So by assumption (2) applied to $Y$ we get that $f_O$ is also continuous from $(X,\mathcal{T}_2)$ and so $O=f_O^{-1}[\{0\}] \in \mathcal{T}_2$, so that $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$. The same idea proves the reverse inclusion from $(2)$ as well.

Bonus exercise: can you also show it only from assumption (1) for some fixed $Y$ as well?